# What does "when you pin me" mean?

Tags: velvet-goldmine

In Velvet Goldmine, Jerry Devine tells Brian Slade's manager that he'll reveal his plan to make Brian a star:

> I will tell you, sir. When you pin me.

It looks like he means an arm-wrestling bout at that point, but the manager's reaction ("I never... in all my life...") makes it seem like there might be an underlying meaning I'm missing. Is there, or am I just reading too much into this scene?

Comment: Film script is [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20050104095225/http://www.geocities.com/moulingoldmine4/VGscript.html) if that's any help.

Comment: I've not seen this film, but a cursory glance at the script would suggest that Devine is challenging Cecil for the rights to manage Brian. Cecil seems to be reacting to the implied threat of violence (fighting someone for a business deal?!) as well as the more overtly sexual connotations.

Comment: Interesting [examination of the scene](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=JTJpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=velvet+Goldmine+%22pin+me%22&source=bl&ots=wf8Zg6GaXh&sig=8e_9AGYaTscFSEl4L5lAP372qj0&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=velvet%20Goldmine%20%22pin%20me%22&f=false) here